# Understanding convergence critieria for linear system iterative methods

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For an iterative method, that solves a system of linear equations of unknown vector $\Phi$, starting from initial guess $\Phi^{(0)} \ne \Phi$, as the number of iterations $n$ increase the method shall ensure that $\Phi^{(n)}$ will converge to $\Phi$.

If one needs to express $\Phi^{(n)}$  in terms of initial guess, starting from $A\Phi = B$, then decomposing $A$ as $A=M-N$, then $(M - N)\Phi = b$, and by applying a fixed point iteration procedure: $M\Phi^{(n)}=N\Phi^{(n-1)}+b$, once can write:

$$\Phi^{(n)} = \text{B}^{n} \Phi^{(0)} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\text{B}^{i}Cb$$

Where $\text{B}=M^{-1}N$ and $C = M^{-1}$

Now, for the above convergence statement to be true, my textbook states that $\text{B}$ should satisfy:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \text{B}^n =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \text{B} * \text{B} * \text{B} * \ ... \ * \text{B} = 0 $$

which also implies that the spectral radius of $\text{B}$ should be less than 1.

I don't understand why should that limit hold for the solution to converge, and why should the spectral radius of $\text{B}$ be less than one?

Answer (score 2):

It's because we must have $\Phi^n=\Phi^{n-1}$ at convergence. That is,
$$
\Phi^n-\Phi^{n-1} = (B^n-B^{n-1})\Phi^0 + B^{n-1}Cb =0
$$
which is true if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} B^n =0$.